# pxssh login issue to router cli interface

Tags: python, linux

Hi i am trying to automate to get some data from ruckless wireless router.

I used the following code

```
 import pxssh
 s = pxssh.pxssh()
 s.login('192.168.2.100','admin','admin')
```

And when i try to login itself i am getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py", line 321, in login
   raise ExceptionPxssh ('could not set shell prompt\n'+self.before)
  pexpect.pxssh.ExceptionPxssh: could not set shell prompt

Please login: unset PROMPT_COMMAND
Password: 
Login incorrect

Please login: set prompt='[PEXPECT]\$ '
Password:
```

And this is not a normal bash shell like linux. I guess it has its own embedded OS and their own shell.

How can i login and create a session. so that i can automate few tasks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use paramiko ssh client for Python. It worked for me.
You can use pip to install it.

apt-get install python-pip

pip install paramiko

Here you can find how to use:

http://www.minvolai.com/blog/2009/09/how-to-ssh-in-python-using-paramiko/

http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different

Comment: thanks. However i used pexpect module and it worked.